# Select top 10 users ordered by amount spent

Tags: mysql

So I have a table as the following:

```
|     steamid | payment_amount |
       199  5.00
       501  10.00
       199  15.00
       238  5.00
       238  1.00
```

Desired Output:

```
 199 20.00
 501 10.00
 238 6.00
```

I've attempted to select the data, grouped by the steamid with a sum of payment_amount, but it's not coming out as expected?

For example:

```
SELECT steamid, sum(payment_amount) AS total FROM payments GROUP BY steamid
```

Comment: What does come out instead? Your query looks actually OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Add `ORDER BY total DESC` to sort the result in descending order
- Add `LIMIT 10` to select top 10

Resulting statement:

```
SELECT steamid, sum(payment_amount) AS total FROM payments GROUP BY steamid ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT steamid, SUM(payment_amount) AS total FROM payments GROUP BY steamid ORDER BY total DESC`

You can achieve result with a minor change in your query by adding order by total desc as mentioned in above query.